# Programmatically get all names of an entity reference field

Tags: 8, entities

Example: I want to get **all tag names** that are inside **field_tags** of node 5.

I can get the target_id with $node->field_tags->[getValue()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!src!Plugin!views!field!Field.php/function/Field%3A%3AgetValue/8.2.x);

[image]

But the problem is, I don't know what entity the target_id value belongs to. Could be a node id, term id, user id. Without that info, I am not able to use the target_id to get the name of the tag.

How can I get all the names of an entity reference field?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest way to get what you want is something like this:

```
$names = [];
foreach ($node->field_tags as $item) {
  if ($item->entity) {
    $names[$item->entity->id()] = $item->entity->label();
  }
}
```

`->entity` is a so called computed property, it doesn't show up in `getValues()`. All reference fields have it.

And yes, forget about `print_r()` on entity or other complex objects. They contain objects that reference each other, and `print_r()` can't handle that. If you have an entity, always use `print_r($entity->toArray())`, then you get the field values only. You could install devel module or use a debugger, but that will give you the internal structure of an entity, which is not really want you want to see.

Comment: `$node->toArray();` sure looks a lot more shorter & cleaner than using `\Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'article');`

Comment: Where do you find documentation on this?

Comment: You can find some information here for example: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api

Comment: @Berdir: `print_r($entity->toArray())` It solves this issue. I can able to get all fields details. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Berdir can you be more specific about the documentation?  I've been looking through that page but don't see any specific examples related to term reference fields.

Answer (score 8):

An entity reference field, by definition, can only target one entity type so you can know what your target type is by calling up [`getSetting()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21src%21Entity%21FieldStorageConfig.php/function/FieldStorageConfig%3A%3AgetSettings/8.2.x) on the field definition.

```
// Print the targeted entity type field.
$field = \Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('node','field_tags');
echo $field->getSetting('target_type');
```

Or better yet, use [`EntityReferenceFieldItemList::referencedEntities()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Field!EntityReferenceFieldItemList.php/function/EntityReferenceFieldItemList%3A%3AreferencedEntities/8.2.x) to pull up the node's referenced entities and the associated data you need.

```
// Return an array of Entity objects referenced in the field.
$node->field_tags->referencedEntities();
```

Comment: `print_r($node->field_tag->referencedEntities());` seems to be a resource hog, I had upgrade my [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) instance, just to be able to do it, since I kept getting WSOD.

Comment: Let me know if this should be a separate question. How can I access the name value, when in the array it says [values:protected](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rUuSh.jpg) which means it can only be accessed inside the class.

Comment: I feel bad about un-accepting your answer, but @Berdir answer gave me no choice but to. I never figured out how to get the value using your `Or better yet` method. The first method is good, but it will require if statements to check the target type and then get the value. Berdir's answer is more efficient as there is no need for checks.

Comment: Don't sweat it (...pun intended). The first version of your question wasn't too clear on your objective. You should mark the answer that best fits.

Comment: I really wish this answer wasn't buried within this SO post.  I wanted to get the `target_type` value from an `entity_reference` field and searched high-and-low for it... until you answered my question here.