# How to get reference field value in term object?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I have term object with referance field .How to get values for referance ids.Please check attached srceenshot of my term object.[image]

I tried this but it return nothing

```
 $ids = array_column($term_object->field_aktivitaetsbild->getValue(), 'target_id');
kint($ids);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the IDs like this:

```
$target_ids = [];

foreach ($term_object->field_aktivitaetsbild as $item) {
  if ($item->entity) {
    $target_ids[] = $item->entity->id();
  }
}
```

<sub>Source: [Programmatically get all names of an entity reference field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212982/programmatically-get-all-names-of-an-entity-reference-field).</sub>

Comment: Actually, if you just want the id, then you can just use $item->target_id. But usually getting the id is just the first step for getting the label or something else from the entity.