# How to display field_tags of a node in html.html.twig?

Tags: theming

I want to display fields "*field_summary*" and "*field_tags"* of a node in html.html.twig (without using a module for that). I was already able to get "*field_summary*" value in html.html.twig with this code:

```
function universaldenker_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  $variables['node_summary'] = $node->get('field_summary')->value;
  $variables['node_tags'] = $node->get('field_tags')->getString();
}
```

Then I just used **{{ node_summary }}** in html.html.twig. It works perfectly. But I couln't display values of "field_tags". If I use **{{ node_tags|join(', ') }}** then I get the field_tags ID's.

How can I get the values and not ID's?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! 1. Don't manually tweak the HTML template to print node values. Why exactly do you want to do that? What exactly do you want to achieve? Did you consider using a Views block for that, which prints a certain view mode of the current node, and this view mode only displays the summary and the tags fields? 2. You'd need to check if `$node` actually is a node or not. Since the HTML template also gets called on non-nodes. 3. You'd need to load the terms yourself first and then pass the title or a render array to the template.

Comment: Or maybe you are looking for the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module. This lets you configure any node fields to be used as meta keywords or meta description in the HTML head.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Drupal and PHP and try to transfer my Website from Ucoz to Drupal. I want to display node_tags as meta keywords and node_summary as meta description in the head region of html.html.twig. What is the best way to achieve this without installing a module? With Views? Thank you!

Comment: `How can I get the values and not ID's?` I asked the same question 4 years ago, [Programmatically get all names of an entity reference field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212982/programmatically-get-all-names-of-an-entity-reference-field)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me! This is what I did:
`$tags = [];
$i = 0;
foreach($node->field_tags as $tag){
array_push($tags, $node->field_tags[$i]->entity->label());
$i++;
}
$variables['node_tags'] = $tags;`

Comment: You really should use Metatag for this.